# javaw.exe isn't running as an executable

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, java

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate x64, SP1 and latest updates are installed. Any time I attempt to open a Java application, I receive a dialog asking what program I want to open javaw.exe with. This problem first appeared while I was using version 8 update 31. Updating to update 45 did not fix the problem. Is there a method to fix this?

Comment: "Any time I attempt to open a Java application" - Do you mean any time you double-click a JAR file?

Comment: That isn't directly the issue, although any .jar files don't appear when opened, if they're opening. Applications that use Java (my example is Yawcam, a webcam photography program) don't open and instead show the "Choose application..." dialog.

Comment: Side note: I am referring to .exe files that use Java to run their code, sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: Try [JavaRa](https://singularlabs.com/software/javara/) to completely uninstall all JRE versions, reboot and install the latest one. See if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue on my machine. Check your Windows Path variable. My path linked Java via `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` and that folder contained symlinks to the actual executables located under `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin`. I deleted the the `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` entry and replaced it with `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin` then everything started working.

Notice however, that the 'correct' directory has a version number, so anytime Java is updated, you'll have to change the Path again. I suspect this was the reason for the other directory.

**EDIT:** Instead of deleting the path entry, you can 'fix" the symlinks in the javapath directory with this command (it makes them hard links):

```
mklink /H C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe
```

Use that command to fix all three links:

- java.exe
- javaw.exe
- javaws.exe

This has also worked for me